# REGEX or Lucene for java web application

Tags: java, mysql, regex, lucene

I'm working on a java web application which is a sort of job portal. When the user enters the key words they need to be searched in the database in a few fields, for instance job details fields, company name, etc. Shall I use the REGEX option provided by mysql or should I use Lucene?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the "AutoComplete" option that's what most of them use ;) For more info on AutoComplete have a look here with Demo. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not understanding your Question properly, I strongly recommend for you to Use LIKE compared to REGEX. Like is faster than REGEX.

Many REGEX is used on Complex text search, very useful but slow's down the processing to 10 times.

To know more differentiation between REGEX and LIKE go here http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/

Hope this helps!!!

Regards,
Zak

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see any kind of performance, you'll have to use Lucene, except if the table you are searching is small enough to make full table scan feasible.